# NodeJs - Error: Can't set headers after they are sent & TypeError: req.next is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

I am trying to get some results from the database mysql. I am calling a method to insert into database and another one to read what I inserted before.

I am doing this because node.js not working synchronous. This is my code:

```
exports.list = function(req, res){

  var moduleRows;

  req.getConnection(function(err,connection){
        var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM questions WHERE module_id = ?',[X],function(err,rows)
        {
            for(var i = 0;i < rows.length;i++){
                moduleRows = rows[i];
                GetResults(moduleRows); 
            }
        });

        var GetResults = function(moduleRows) {
            var RightAnswer = 0;
            var WrongAnswer1 = 0;
            var query = connection.query("SELECT * FROM studentsanswers WHERE Question = '"+moduleRows.question+"' ",function(err,rows2)
            {
                    for(var ii = 0;ii < rows2.length;ii++){
                        if (rows2[ii].Answer == moduleRows.RightAnswer){
                            RightAnswer++;
                        }
                        else if (rows2[ii].Answer == moduleRows.WrongAnswer1){
                            WrongAnswer1++;
                        }
                    }
                var Data = {
                    question: moduleRows.question,
                    RightAnswer: moduleRows.RightAnswer,
                    WrongAnswer1: moduleRows.WrongAnswer1,
                    NumberOfRightAnswer: RightAnswer,
                    NumberOfWrongAnswer1 : WrongAnswer1
                };
                insertResults(Data);
                return;
            });
        }

        var insertResults = function(Data) {
            var query = connection.query("INSERT INTO statistics set ? ",Data, function(err, rows)
                {   
                    PrintResults();
                    return;
                });
        }

        var PrintResults = function() {
            var query = connection.query("SELECT * FROM statistics" ,function(err,rows)
            {
                res.render('StatisticsByModules',{page_title:"Questions - Node.js",data:rows});
                return;
            }); 
        }
    });

};
```

I am getting the errors: 
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
TypeError: req.next is not a function

Comment: Could you give the code snippet of place where this module is used?

Comment: Have you added the full code ? your saying your getting **req.next is not a function** error but it's not even used in the code

Answer (score 0):

In following code, you call `GetResults(moduleRows)` few times which calls `PrintResults` Few times, In your `PrintResults` Method you are sending `res.render` few time which you cannot do for a single request. First, you will have to make your data list then call `req.render` once with queried data.

```
var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM questions WHERE module_id = ?', [X], function (err, rows) {
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { // <== HERE
        moduleRows = rows[i];
        GetResults(moduleRows);
    }
});
```